# Laravel query slower than phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, laravel

When I run one query in laravel takes 30 seconds. But when I  run exactly this query in phpmyadmin only 2.5 seconds takes to response. What is the reason for this difference?

**phpmyadmin**:

```
select count(counter) as total from (SELECT count(ip) as counter FROM `counter` group by ip) as new_table
```

**laravel 5.7**:

```
$count=DB::select(DB::raw("select count(counter) as total from (SELECT count(ip) as counter FROM `counter` group by ip) as new_table"));
```

Comment: Do you have XDebug enabled? Where are you using the query?

Comment: for total count of visitor by ip

Comment: Seems like this would give you the same answer, but much faster:  `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IP) FROM counter;`

Comment: If you ran it in laravel first, then phpmyadmin, mysql will have the results cached, so it wont run the query from the ground up again.